# solving third order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

Can someone help me in solving :
$$
y'''(x)+2\,y(x)y''(x)=0
$$
using Runge-Kutta method? I'm not sure how to linearize it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To apply a RK method, you need not to linearize, but to transform into a first order system. Assign to a state vector $u\in\Bbb R^3$ the intended meaning $u_0=y$, $u_1=y'$, $u_2=y''$, then the ODE function in $u'(t)=F(t,u(t))$ is
$$
F(t,u)=\pmatrix{u_1\\u_2\\-2u_0u_2}
$$